# Efficient way of reaching a destination from an origin C#

Tags: c#, .net, graph-theory, shortest-path

I have this `Flight` class:

```
public class Flight
{
    public string Origin { get; set; }
    public string Destination { get; set; }   
    public decimal Price { get; set; } 
}
```

Let's say a user wants to travel from India to China. It might be the case that an India-China pair is not available in a list of `Flight` objects, but it's possible to achieve this by "hopping" between `Flight` objects, e.g.:

```
India-Budapest 100EUR
Budapest-Romania 200EUR
Romania-China 100EUR
```

The result would be India -> Budapest -> Romania -> China and the cost would be 400 EUR.

I want to be able to identify, in the following order:

1. A direct flight, and if not:
2. The shortest amount of hops to achieve the flight, if such a hop/combo exists.

I'm looking for the least amount of flights rather than least distance. All are equal weighted.

I can brute force this, by first checking that any such `Origin`-`Destination` pair exists for a given `Flight` object, and if not, find `Destination` matches and try to go backwards, but this seems like a slow implementation.

What would be the best way to achieve this rather than brute forcing the solution?

Comment: This is a common problem with a famous solution: **Dijkstra’s shortest path algorithm**  There's even an entire tag for it here on Stack Overflow: [tag:shortest-path], which I have added to your question.  The science of analyzing sets of paths (edges) connecting cities (vertexes / nodes) is named **Graph Theory**, there's a tag for that too.  And the general category of algorithms which do optimization without brute force and includes Djisktra's SPA is **Dynamic Programming**

Comment: Is 2 hops always shorter than 3? Would india-london-china be shorter than india-pakistan-nepal-china despite the latter being less distance (ie... Do you have weighted edges?)

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 for this particular use-case yes, 2 hops is always shorter than 3. Looking for the least amount of flights rather than least distance.

Comment: @globetrotter you should likely add that as a clarification to your question. I doubt I'll be the first to wonder

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 amended thank you

Comment: Fewest hops is the same algorithm as shortest distance, just weight every route as the same number. Either way, you're still asking for a very complex computer science algorithm such as Dijkstra's (thanks @BenVoigt for giving me flashbacks to my CompSci degree)

Comment: @DavidG: actually, all equal weights does simplify matters... the waiting queue becomes sorted by always appending to the tail, and you'll never find a reduced cost for a node already sitting in the queue.  So one could remove the sorting bits and call it a simpler algorithm.